# Installing Homestead files not syncing

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I am stuck on installing Homestead. I am at the point where I am able to SSH into Vagrant but when I do so it isn't showing me any directories I created, in this case the dir named 'code' as per the tutorial I am following.

I am using:

- Virtualbox 5.0.26
- Homestead
- Vagrant 1.8.4
- Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11

Also when I visit the IP from the YAML file it just times out, interestingly though if I launch MAMP and I then revisit the site name 'fresh.app' it takes me to localhost, but if I quit MAMP it then times out...

So, to test I switched the ports in MAMP from using port 80 to start using 8888 and using 'fresh.app' as my address failed. Port issue or? Im new to this so please accept my apology if it something silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I've only used Homestead with Linux and Windows. However, from what I'm understanding, you shouldn't be using MAMP at all. Here are a couple of points to be aware of:

- Have you entered fresh.app to point to the VM's IP in your hosts file (/etc/hosts)? I think this is the reason you are getting the time out.
- Are you sure that the VM's subnet is not in use?
- Have you tried using Laravel Valet which is specific for Mac developers? (check it out here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/valet)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in regards to point #2 inside of etc/hosts what should I be putting because no I have not done this.

Comment: Also, to add, I have completely removed MAMP from my device...

Comment: In the hosts file it has a line `127.0.0.1 fresh.app` already...

Comment: Assuming that the VM's virtual IP address is 192.168.10.10 (this is the default one) and you've mapped the fresh.app domain in your YAML file, you need to have the following line in your hosts file:


`192.168.10.10    fresh.app`

Comment: How can I check if the IP is as stated inside of the virtualbox?

Comment: I found t sorry under network settings

Comment: You should just be checking your `Homestead.yaml` file. If you insist on using homestead, please read this (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead). Still, I would recommend switching to Valet (if possible).

Comment: I am following a tutorial thats all so I will 100% check out Valet. This is very confusing because in the yaml file is does indeed show the IP as `192.168.10.10`

Comment: The VM is running and there where no errors in terminal when `vagrant up` was ran?

Comment: In a nutshell, VirtualBox creates a virtual network interface card with its own mac address and then maps the IP `192.168.10.10` to that NIC. This is why you shouldn't use localhost. The virtual machine is actually located (from your PCs point of view) on `192.168.10.10`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122925/discussion-between-dan-and-theodore-messinezis).